# $X/\ker A \cong \operatorname{ran} A$ iff $\operatorname{ran}A$ is closed

Tags: functional-analysis

$X, Y$ are Banach spaces, $A \in B(X, Y)$. To show that $X/\ ker A \cong \operatorname{ran}A$ iff $\operatorname{ran}A$ is closed.

My approach: I can define $A' : X/ \ker A \to Y$ by taking $A'([x])=Ax$ and now I have an injective map from $\operatorname{ran}A$ to $Y$. I think I have to apply open mapping theorem somehow but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

($\implies$): Apply the open mapping theorem on the operator you have defined (since the range of A is closed, it is a Banach space).

($\impliedby$): Completeness is a three space property, so if  X and $\ker A$ are complete (Banach) spaces, so is $X / \ker A$.